# Divi Contact Form Help - Can I align certain elements on one side instead of default ordering?

Tags: css

Is there a way for me to order the modules in the divi contact form differently than their default ordering? Possibly, some custom CSS?

Here is a link that shows what I have vs. what I want. 
(Keep in mind: the what I want part is an image, not an actual contact form.)

https://mastermclaren.com/89-2/

Thank you for your time, help, and advice!

Comment: post ur code what you tried before

Comment: you can create 2 divs in your form having 50% width, then put three colums in one and rest in other.. if u need more explanation then tell me , i ll provide u code as well.. and for that you must provide your html and css to me before... thank you